# C: measure time of operation in Linux

Tags: c, linux, time, system-calls

I need to measure a time inside the C program. I googled and found two options: `gettimeofday()` and `time()` syscalls. For example:

```
#include <time.h>

...

time_t start, end;
double seconds;

time(&start);

/* Run some complex algorithm  ... */

time(&end);
seconds = difftime(end, start);
```

Or

```
#include <sys/time.h>
...
struct timeval start, end;
double elapsed_time;

gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

/* Data processing */

gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

/* calculate time in ms. */
elapsed_time = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000.0;
elapsed_time += (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0;
```

So as I understand, the 2nd method is giving higher accuracy (milli/microseconds), while the first one returns elapsed time only in seconds. Am I right?

Comment: Slightly off topic but relevant, look at timercmp(3) to see the best way to do math on struct timeval values, because there are subtle gotchas with the subtraction as you did it - look at timersub() in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

There is also `clock_gettime` which provides nanosecond resolution.  (Whether it actually has nanosecond *accuracy* depends on your hardware.)